# extracting and listing word in python

Tags: python, regex, project, extract

i have difficult to do this project 
python script to extract and list all words that meets the following conditions:

(1) words with two consonants next to each other.
(2) words of length 5 or more that start and ends with a vowel.
(3) words of length 7 or more that starts with consonant and ends with a vowel.
(4) Abbreviate 2-3 words that all start with a capital letter.

Any pointers on how to code this, helps, or even code examples would be much appreciated.
need your help.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Downvoters, don't forget that it is a first post.

Comment: You must add to your post what you have tried, because nobody here will write a complete code for you.

Comment: It also looks suspiciously like a homework assignment, and no one here will do that for you.

Comment: @r3mus: there are any homeworks that are interesting or funny.

Comment: Tips: you can do `string[0]` and `string[-1]` to find the first and last letters of a string respectively. You can also do `character in string` to find out if a character is in a string. For instance, you might want to do `character in string_of_vowels`.

Comment: I miss the "minimal understanding" and "include attempted solutions" reasons for a question being off-topic... :,(

Comment: @iCodez Yeah, what happened there? Where's the meta thread discussing the change?

Comment: @iCodez "Minimal understanding" is still in the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) though. And on the other hand, they've added "simple typographical error" as a reason, presumably for cases involving missing semi-colons and the like.

Comment: @sweeneyrod - True, but none of the off-topic reasons we have now accurately fill the void left by the ones they removed.  I think they should bring them back.  At the very least do the "attempted solutions" one.

Comment: @iCodez I agree, I wouldn't say that any of the existing things really fits into the category of "no work put in by OP". I suppose that the nearest are "very low quality" and "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: The only rule that seems too broad is the fourth. How looks like exactly "Abbreviate 2-3 words"?

Answer (score 3):

First, how to include regular expressions in a Python program:

```
import re

if re.match(pattern, string_to_match):
    # there is a match
else:
    # there is no match
```

Then, the first regular expression you need. As you haven't given any code, and this question smells of homework I won't give you the others.

```
 re.match(r"^[aeiou].{,3}[aeiou]$", string_to_match)
```

Explanation:

The `^` and `$` ensure that the match is from the beginning to end of the string.
The `[aeiou]` checks for a character that is a vowel.
The `.{,3}` checks for up to 3 repetitions of any character (represented by `.`).

You may find the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"+"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".upper()
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
```

a word has 2 consonants if

```
re.find("[%s]{2,}"%consonants,the_word_to_check)
```

a word is longer than 5 if `len(the_word) > 5`

a word starts and ends with a vowel if `re.match("^[{0}].*[{0}]$".format(vowels),the_word)`

I'll leave the rest as an excersize for you ...